# How to load image, create texture, render, and save image asynchronously with WebGL?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webgl

I am attempting to write an application that uses very large textures. The idea is that you work on a scaled version of the texture in realtime modifying shaders and when finished the application would apply your changes to the original unscaled (large) texture. The problem is that profiling shows something like the following:

- img.src = filename (500ms)
- texImage2d(...) (1500ms)
- bind/rendering (100ms)
- readPixels (300ms)
- Put into canvas (1000ms)
- Save canvas to file (300ms)

Essentially this means the browser locks up for almost four seconds when saving the larger unscaled texture, with the user unable to do anything. Is it possible to do this asynchronously so that the browser stays responsive? It needs to all be done in javascript and client-side, as I'm using local files (HTML5 file/filesystem).

Web workers sounded like a good idea, but they are unable to access the DOM, so I can't use the browser's image loading and saving functionality, and they have no access to the WebGL context so they can't call texImage2d, which takes the most time.

Due to the size and number of images I cannot load them all into memory as textures when the page initially loads.

Is there anything that can be done to make this more responsive to the user? I'd like them to be able to continue working on the next image while the previous one renders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image loading should happen in the background, and you'll get no idea of progress for it, but you could use `texSubImage2D` to incrementally upload the texture.  That will probably take a little bit longer overall but you should be able to give the user some feedback and respond to other events.

Also, you can just draw the webgl canvas directly into the canvas 2D.  `drawImage()` takes images, video and canvas (2D or webgl) elements as arguments.  That should happen almost instantaneously and save about 1300 ms.

Comment: Thanks, passing the canvas directly to drawImage is saving a lot of time. Using texSubImage2D does seem to help a lot as well.

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, I was mistaken. The drawImage call is faster but it turns out it was just writing black rectangles rather than the image data.

Comment: Now *that* is weird.  It works for me with FF on Win7 and OS X, but when I try it in Chrome, it not only doesn't work, it clears the WebGL canvas when I try to draw it to the 2D one!

Comment: It appears the preserveDrawingBuffer WebGL context attribute will fix this behavior, e.g. canvas.getContext('webgl', { preserveDrawingBuffer: true }); After setting that it now draws properly in Chrome, so I can in fact use drawImage!

Answer (score 1):

This question is old but to others who find it here's some updated info

- You can consider using [`OffscreenCanvas`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) which has been shipping in Chrome since January 2019. Unfortunately it's not shipping anywhere else ATM
- These 3 synchronous steps

  ```
  readPixels (300ms)
  Put into canvas (1000ms)
  Save canvas to file (300ms)
  ```

  can be turned into 1 asynchronous step

  ```
  gl.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // url is now something you can give the user to download
  });
  ```
- for rendering really large images (say 16k by 16k) you can render smaller portions and assemble them into a larger image.

  There's a library for that here: https://greggman.github.io/dekapng/